# How to insert a Polygon into MySQL database Table?

Tags: mysql, python-3

I have shapefiles which I converted to `.csv` format. I want to insert those into a MySQL Database table. I used [ST_PolyFromText](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-polyfromtext) according to the MySQL reference manual.

```
## create table
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE `db1`.`table1` ("
  "`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
  "`geometry` POLYGON NOT NULL,"
  "PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));")

sql_statement = "INSERT INTO table1(geometry) VALUES (ST_PolyFromText(%s,0))"
```

When I try to insert polygon values into the Database. I get the error    **3037, 'Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polyfromtext.'**

1. How should I use MySQL [Spatial Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-function-reference.html) to insert my Polygons ??

My Polygon geometry column looks like this :
[image]

Comment: I tried it out , still I am getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

To insert polygon values into a MySQL database using the ST_PolyFromText function, you need to ensure that the text representation of your polygons is in the correct format. The format should adhere to the Well-Known Text (WKT) standard.

Steps:
-Read the CSV file.
-Iterate over the rows and extract the WKT geometry.
-Insert the WKT geometry into the MySQL table using the ST_PolyFromText function.

python_code

```
import csv
import mysql.connector

# Connect to the MySQL database
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="your_host",
    user="your_username",
    password="your_password",
    database="db1"
)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Create the table if it doesn't exist
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` ("
            "`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            "`geometry` POLYGON NOT NULL,"
            "PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));")

# Read the CSV file and insert polygon geometries into the table
with open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip header if exists
    for row in reader:
        # Assuming the polygon geometry is in the second column (index 1)
        polygon_wkt = row[1]
        # Insert the polygon geometry using ST_PolyFromText
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO table1(geometry) VALUES (ST_PolyFromText(%s,0))", (polygon_wkt,))

# Commit changes and close connection
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```